# How to call the a function within itself and have it reselect a new DOM element in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a function A to select the `.current` element and do something to it. Then, (re)move the `.current` class name to another element and do the same thing to it.

```
function funA () {
    let state = []; 
    let currentRow = document.querySelector(".current");
    //...
    evaluateThings(function () {
        currentRow.classList.remove("current");
        currentRow.nextSibling.classList.add("current");
         funcA();
    });
}
function evaluateThings(callback) {
    //...
    callback()
}

funcA()
```

The issue is, `funcA` remembers the previous selector and makes changes to both, the new `.current` and the last one

[here's a demo](https://jsbin.com/jiyeyehogo/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Why don’t you try waiting for a while until the dom gets updated before you call funA again? Maybe a little timeout might help.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I created a demo https://jsbin.com/jiyeyehogo/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Chin.Udara I created a demo https://jsbin.com/jiyeyehogo/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you click it again, you might have clicked on the bad like I already edited https://jsbin.com/jiyeyehogo/2/edit?html,js,output

Start typing, then hit enter and you'll see my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`funcA` adds a keydown listener to the document. When you recursively call `funcA`, you aren't removing the previous listener, so on the next event, both run, and both elements get changed - and the cycle continues.

Remove the prior listener when doing the recursive call.

```js
function funcA() {
  const currentRow = document.querySelector(".current");
  const handler = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      currentRow.nextElementSibling.classList.add("current");
      currentRow.classList.remove("current");
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
      evaluateThings(funcA);
    } else {
      currentRow.innerHTML += e.key
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
}

function evaluateThings(callback) {
  //...
  callback()
}

funcA()
```

```html
<div class="row current">a</div>
<div class="row">b</div>
<div class="row">c</div>
<div class="row">d</div>
<div class="row">e</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Or keep the listener attached, but reassign the variable that points to the element.

```js
let currentRow = document.querySelector(".current");
function funcA() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      currentRow.nextElementSibling.classList.add("current");
      currentRow.classList.remove("current");
      evaluateThings(() => currentRow = document.querySelector(".current"));
    } else {
      currentRow.innerHTML += e.key;
    }
  });
}

function evaluateThings(callback) {
  //...
  callback()
}

funcA()
```

```html
<div class="row current">a</div>
<div class="row">b</div>
<div class="row">c</div>
<div class="row">d</div>
<div class="row">e</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```